# Doing Math with Gravity Forms List

Tags: jquery, plugin-gravity-forms

While working on a client site utilizing Gravity Forms, I found myself wanting to use the aesthetic of the advanced list Gravity provides, but needed a bit more arithmetic firepower (read: any, arithmetic firepower; gravity doesn't enable calculations on their advanced list field without a plugin).

I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872452/gravity-forms-find-sum-of-list-column
Which got me close to what I was after, but I also needed to do some pre-calculations within each row. That is, given I have cells A, B, C, and D. I needed to do math on A and B, and then store it in C. Then, I needed to find the sum of all C cells in all rows.

First the starting code:

```
// ************      Gravity Forms Dynamic List Summation ************** //
//EX:  listFieldColumnTotal( 140, 1, 3, 3, true );
//The elements are described in the function, but are described in order as follows:
//
//The Form ID (ex. gform_wrapper_6)
//The list container's ID (ex. #field_6_7)
//The column item which we want to use as the dynamic value which lives beneath the list container 
// (ex. .gfield_list_7_cell2)
//The id of the result input's container (ex. field_6_18)
//defines whether or not we're using a currency (I didn't experiment with this value set to "false", 
// but I imagine it works the same
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      function calculateLFColumnTotal(formId, columnClass, totalFieldId, currency) {
        var columnTotal = 0,
            preField = '#field_' + formId + '_' + totalFieldId,
            totalField = jQuery('#input_' + formId + '_' + totalFieldId),
            cellValue;
        currency = (currency && typeof gf_global !== 'undefined');
        jQuery(columnClass).each(function () {
            cellValue = jQuery(this).val();
            cellValue = (currency) ? gformToNumber(cellValue) : cellValue;
            columnTotal += parseFloat(cellValue) || 0;
        });
        if (jQuery(preField).hasClass('gfield_price')) {
            columnTotal = gformFormatMoney(columnTotal);
            if (jQuery(preField + ' input').length > 1) {
                totalField.html(columnTotal);
                totalField = jQuery('input[name="input_' + totalFieldId + '.2"]');

            }
        } else {
            columnTotal = (currency) ? gformFormatMoney(columnTotal) : columnTotal;
        }

        totalField.val(columnTotal);
        gformCalculateTotalPrice(formId);

    }

    function listFieldColumnTotal(formId, fieldId, column, totalFieldId, currency) {
        var listField = '#field_' + formId + '_' + fieldId,
            columnClass = '.gfield_list_' + fieldId + '_cell' + column + ' input';
        
        jQuery(listField).on('focusout', columnClass, function () {

            if (currency && typeof gf_global !== 'undefined') {
                gformFormatPricingField(this);
            }
            calculateLFColumnTotal(formId, columnClass, totalFieldId, currency);

        });

        jQuery(listField).on('click', '.add_list_item', function () {
            jQuery(listField + ' .delete_list_item').removeProp('onclick');
        });

        jQuery(listField).on('click', '.delete_list_item', function () {
            gformDeleteListItem(this, 0);
            calculateLFColumnTotal(formId, columnClass, totalFieldId, currency);
        });
      }
 listFieldColumnTotal( 6, 120, 3, 47, true );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

And now for the final, largely untested, code. In the end I wasn't sure which operations I'd need to be doing and so wanted to expand the functionality for whatever my client might throw at me in the future. I just got so excited that the ['*','+'] case worked after two days of trying to figure this out, I wanted to share it in hopes it might help someone else.

```
// ************      Gravity Forms Dynamic List Calculations ************** //
//EX:  listFieldColumnTotal( 6, 120, 2, 3, 4,'*', '+', 47, true );
//EX:  listFieldColumnTotal( FormID, listContainerID, FirstRowOperand, SecondRowOperand, RowResult, RowOperator, ColumnOperator, ColumnOperatorFieldID, isCurrency );;
//The elements are described in the function, but are described in order as follows:
//
//Form ID (ex. gform_wrapper_6)
//ListContainerID (ex. #field_6_120)
//FirstRowOperand: The first column we want to do math with
//SecondRowOperand: The first column we want to do math with
//RowResult: The column we want to store the result of the: FirstRowOperand [RowOperator] SecondRowOperand
//RowOperator: '*','+','-','/'
//ColumnOperator: '*','+','-','/'
//ColumnOperatorFieldID (ex. .gfield_list_7_cell2): "Take all of the results stored in the RowResul fields and [ColumnOperator] them together and put the result here"
//defines whether or not we're using a currency (I didn't experiment with this value set to "false", but I imagine it works the same
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
          function calculateLFColumnTotal(formId, columnClassA,columnClassB, columnClassResult, operatorAB,operatorR, totalFieldId, currency) {
            var subTotal = 0,
                columnTotal = 0,
                preField = '#field_' + formId + '_' + totalFieldId,             
                totalField = jQuery('#input_' + formId + '_' + totalFieldId),               
                cellValue;                
                currency = (currency && typeof gf_global !== 'undefined');

            //Go through and get all of the values from the first column
            var listA = [];            
            jQuery(columnClassA).each(function () {
                cellValueA = jQuery(this).val();
                cellValueA = (currency) ? gformToNumber(cellValueA) : cellValueA;
                listA.push(cellValueA);                
            });

            //Go through and get all of the values from the second column
            var listB = [];            
            jQuery(columnClassB).each(function () {
                cellValueB = jQuery(this).val();
                cellValueB = (currency) ? gformToNumber(cellValueB) : cellValueB;
                listB.push(cellValueB);               
            });

            
            //Do the appropriate arithmetic on first column and second column values
            var i = 0;
            jQuery(columnClassResult).each(function () {
                                   
                    switch(operatorAB){
                    case "*":
                        subTotal = parseFloat(listA[i]) * parseFloat(listB[i]);
                        break;
                    case "+":
                        subTotal = parseFloat(listA[i]) + parseFloat(listB[i]);
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        subTotal = parseFloat(listA[i]) - parseFloat(listB[i]);
                        break;                      
                    case "/":
                        subTotal = parseFloat(listA[i]) / parseFloat(listB[i]);
                        break;
                    default:
                        subTotal = parseFloat(listA[i]) + parseFloat(listB[i]);
                        break;
                    }

                jQuery(this).val(subTotal);
                i += 1;             
            });


             //Do the appropriate arithmetic on all of the resulting values
             jQuery(columnClassResult).each(function () {
                    cellValue = jQuery(this).val();
                    cellValue = (currency) ? gformToNumber(cellValue) : cellValue;
                           
                    switch(operatorR){
                    case "*":
                        columnTotal *= parseFloat(cellValue) || 0;
                        break;
                    case "+":
                        columnTotal += parseFloat(cellValue) || 0;
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        columnTotal -= parseFloat(cellValue) || 0;
                        break;                      
                    case "/":
                        columnTotal /= parseFloat(cellValue) || 0;
                        break;
                    default:
                        columnTotal += parseFloat(cellValue) || 0;
                        break;
                    }       
            });

        
            if (jQuery(preField).hasClass('gfield_price')) {
                columnTotal = gformFormatMoney(columnTotal);
                if (jQuery(preField + ' input').length > 1) {
                    totalField.html(columnTotal);
                    totalField = jQuery('input[name="input_' + totalFieldId + '.2"]');

                }
            } else {
                columnTotal = (currency) ? gformFormatMoney(columnTotal) : columnTotal;
            }

            totalField.val(columnTotal);
            gformCalculateTotalPrice(formId);

        }

    
        function listFieldColumnTotal(formId, fieldId, columnOperandA, columnOperandB, columnResult, operatorAB, operatorR, totalFieldId, currency) {
            var listField = '#field_' + formId + '_' + fieldId,
                columnClassA = '.gfield_list_' + fieldId + '_cell' + columnOperandA + ' input';
                columnClassB = '.gfield_list_' + fieldId + '_cell' + columnOperandB + ' input';
                columnClassResult = '.gfield_list_' + fieldId + '_cell' + columnResult + ' input';
                
            jQuery(listField).on('focusout', columnClassA, function () {

                if (currency && typeof gf_global !== 'undefined') {
                    gformFormatPricingField(this);
                }
                calculateLFColumnTotal(formId, columnClassA,columnClassB, columnClassResult, operatorAB,operatorR, totalFieldId, currency);

            });

            jQuery(listField).on('focusout',columnClassB, function () {

                if (currency && typeof gf_global !== 'undefined') {
                    gformFormatPricingField(this);
                }
                calculateLFColumnTotal(formId, columnClassA,columnClassB, columnClassResult, operatorAB,operatorR, totalFieldId, currency);

            });

            jQuery(listField).on('focusout',columnClassResult, function () {

                if (currency && typeof gf_global !== 'undefined') {
                    gformFormatPricingField(this);
                }
                calculateLFColumnTotal(formId, columnClassA,columnClassB, columnClassResult, operatorAB,operatorR, totalFieldId, currency);

            });

            jQuery(listField).on('click', '.add_list_item', function () {
                jQuery(listField + ' .delete_list_item').removeProp('onclick');
            });

            jQuery(listField).on('click', '.delete_list_item', function () {
                gformDeleteListItem(this, 0);
                calculateLFColumnTotal(formId,columnClassA,columnClassB, columnClassResult, operatorAB, operatorR, totalFieldId, currency);
            });
          }

 // **Edit this line to reflect your situation!
 listFieldColumnTotal( 1, 22, 2, 3, 4,'*', '+', 50, true );


});
```